# Cassandra stress test fails after large number of inserts

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I've been trying to insert 1 billion records into Cassandra using the stress test and it fails after a couple of million inserts with the following error:

Operation [641412926] retried 10 times - error inserting key 0641412926 ((UnavailableException))

Operation [641412995] retried 10 times - error inserting key 0641412995 ((UnavailableException))

Operation [641413235] retried 10 times - error inserting key 0641413235 ((UnavailableException))

Operation [641413164] retried 10 times - error inserting key 0641413164 ((UnavailableException))

I've observed this issue in every run of my stress test. Sometimes, any one of the nodes in the cluster goes down. Is this a known issue? Any particular reason as to why this is happening? I am using Cassandra 1.2.3 on cluster of 8 machines.

Thanks,
VS

Comment: This in fact happens when a machine (node) goes down in the cluster. Somehow the connection pooling mechanism used in stress test doesn't recover when a machine goes down resulting in the complete crash of the testing process. If anyone has more information, please add to this.

Answer (score 3):

UnavailableException means that the node you've contacted cannot find enough replicas in the cluster for the key requested to fulfill the request. If you have nodes going up and down during your stress test you likely need more capacity to handle the load that you're running against the cluster.

Why is this happening? You're probably under-capacity in some way. If you're not running out of disk space you should evaluate your CPU load, and your IO to try to figure out what's going on. It's important, when using Cassandra, to distinguish between peak load and sustained load. While Cassandra can handle ephemeral peaks it's entirely possible to throw more load at a node than it can handle in the long term. This means that if your peak lasts for five minutes you'll probably be ok. If your peak lasts for days you should add capacity because your cluster is eventually going to fall behind.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is if the node you are inserting to is up and cassandra is running. Assuming it is, then you may be overwhelming cassandra. In general applications running within the JVM are unable to recover when the JVM Garbage Collection process has failed in a catastrophic fashion. This may be the error condition you are triggering, which could be why your Cassandra node does not recover. To confirm whether this is the case, enable more verbose GC logging and/or consult existing JVM GC log messages in system.log.